How to parse/filter incoming SerialPort data in C#?
I have a question about filtering/parse incoming data via the SerialPort in C#. I can receive and read data and show this data in a MessageBox or Console. But now I want to do something if specific data is received. Like: if data "orange" is received via the SerialPort, higher the integer named OrangeDog with 1 (int OrangeDog += 1). I can't get it work till now.
I've tried the following but nothing works:
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
string Data = serialPort1.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine(Data);
MessageBox.Show("Incoming data:" + Data);

if(String.Compare(Data, "orange") == 0) { MessageBox.Show("OrangeDog is raised"); OrangeDog += 1;  }

if(Data == "orange") { MessageBox.Show("OrangeDog is raised"); OrangeDog += 1; }

}

Do I need to convert the incoming Data or what am I doing wrong? Many thanks in advance.

With your comparisons, the line has to be exactly "orange". - case sensitive Maybe you want String.contains()

SerialPort.ReadLine doesn't trim trailing \r, make sure it's 6 chars long.
